# Big O notation of just a return statement?

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Am I right in saying that the time complexity in big O notation would just be O(1)?

```
public boolean size() {
        return (size == 0);
    }
```

Comment: FYI size is a global variable.

Comment: With respect to what `n`?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I need it in the format O(1), O(n), O(log n) etc. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ControlAltDel is not right.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth has the important point here! Also, big-O notation for language constructs *doesn't make any sense*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you tell me why?

Comment: By the way: What sense does a boolen method called `size` have that actually seems to check whether some size is zero (i.e. that a collection is empty)?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose don't you bring logic into this discussion! =)

Comment: Sorry if the code seems funny, I was just using this as an example and 'size' popped into my head.

Comment: @ControlAltDel see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I right in saying that the time complexity in big O notation would just be O(1)?

No.

This is so common a misconception among students/pupils that I can only constantly repeat this:

Big-O notation is meant to give the complexity **of** something, with respect to a certain **measure**, over another **number**:

For example, saying:

> "The algorithm for in-place FFT has a space requirement of O(n), with n being the number of FFT bins"

says something about how much the **FFT** will need in **memory**, observed for different **lengths of the FFT**.

So, you don't specify

1. What is the thing you're actually observing? Is it the time between calling and returning from your method? Is it the comparison alone? Is "time" measured in Java bytecode instructions, or real machine cycles?
2. What do you vary? The number of calls to your method? The variable `size`?
3. What is it that you *actually* want to know?

I'd like to stress 3.: Computer science students often think that they know how something will behave if they just know the theoretical time complexity of an algorithm. In reality, these numbers tend to mean **nothing**. And I mean that. A single fetching of a variable that is not in the CPU cache can take the time of 100-10000 additions in the CPU. Calling a method just to see whether something is 0 will take a few dozen instructions if directly compiled, and might take a lot more if you're using something that is (semi-)interpreted like Java; however, in Java, the next time you call that same method, it might already be there as precompiled machine code...

Then, if your compiler is very smart, it might not only inline the function, eliminating the stack save/restore and call/return instructions, but possibly even merging the result into whatever instructions you were conditioning on that return value, which in essence means that this function, in an extreme case, might not take a single cycle to execute.

So, no matter how you put this, you **can not** say "time complexity in big O of something that is a language specific feature" without saying what you vary, and exactly what your platform is.

Comment: Your argument is totally valid. But what you can ask instead is "What is the complexity of returning the starting memory address of a memory block of size `n`, as a function of `n`?" (which basically is, what Java does when returning an object). And here the answer is O(1).

Comment: @Unfitacorn with what exactly?

Comment: @Turing85 I'd argue that's not fully true. Yes, returning a value would take the arbitrarily defined "one basic Java operation", but what's that worth? Probably nothing, as returning a constant basic type would only in a naive JRE/JIT implementation have exactly the same overhead as passing around a freshly created mutable object. So, the generalization "it always takes the same time" doesn't really apply. Especially as I've seen for Python that for things like small ints and bools, there's only one singleton object that is created once. So O(1) is not even true if your JRE behaves similarly.